# Update to Chrome 36, black screen, no address bar, can't uninstall

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, installation

I just updated to the latest (as of 7/18/14) Chrome, version 36 and when I relaunched the browser, it's just the window frame and a black screen.

It seems like a page (google.com) is loaded but it's just black. I can right click and get context menus, even a "save image" when I click where the google doodle would be. The cursor changes to text insert when hovering near the address bar. So everything's there... but it's not.

I try to uninstall it and a "Are you sure you want to uninstall Chrome?" dialog flashes quickly then disappears. And that's it. Nothing else.

I restarted my computer and ran a registry scan and nothing related to Google or Chrome came up.

I'm on Windows 7 and have all latest updates installed.

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this or force an uninstall?

[image: Chrome 36 black screen]

Comment: [Revo](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) might help you uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work though :( Flashed the "Are you sure?" dialog for a second, and a "uninstall chrome" window appears in the taskbar, but it does nothing. Doesn't even open a window.

Comment: Oohhh. I tried IObit Uninstaller and it worked! Thanks for the advice.

Comment: In the future, if you run the 4th option down for uninstalling (below moderate, can't remember the name..) it will run the applications installer, and once that's done Revo goes through and removes any left over files. Which, in the case where the uninstaller didn't work, removes all of them

Comment: So I reinstalled chrome and still have the black screen issue. Did what you suggested (remove all files) and reinstalled. Still same issue. Makes no sense.

Comment: I'd assume it's a chrome issue, then

Comment: It's starting to look it, but no one else seems to have reported issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, the only answer that did work...

1. Add **--disable-gpu** to the chrome shortcut
2. Chrome should now launch properly
3. Go into settings and **turn off hardware acceleration**

**Add --disable-gpu:**

[image: Add --disable-gpu]

**Turn off hardware acceleration:**

[image: Turn off hardware acceleration]

After you do that you can remove the --disable-gpu flag from your chrome shortcut.

https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/E6auRoL3p3w/2dhxfqStOtcJ (thanks Mindflux!)

Comment: As a shortcut, you can also hold CTRL + ALT when launching Chrome to start it in safe mode, then disable hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

Should anyone find this thread and be looking for a solution for Windows 10, close Chrome and delete the following folder:

```
%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache\GPUCache
```

Then you can start Chrome again.

This happens every time I update the driver for my GeForce GPU, and this solution also works every time.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/ctn3pb/black_chrome_window_after_gpu_swap/