# Graphical artifacts in Google Chrome on Windows

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, nvidia-geforce

For the last week or so, I've been getting a weird visual artifact in Chrome. [This black square](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w3cppiyectn18hv/Screenshot%202014-10-08%2010.30.16.png?dl=0) appears, distorting the screen area around it, and moves around a bit. It's fine for a while after a reboot, then comes back.

This happens ONLY in Chrome (I'm currently on "Version 39.0.2171.13 dev-m"), no other applications seem to be affected, games perform fine as normal. My graphics card is a Nvidia GTX 670, made by EVGA, with GeForce Experience driver v344.11.

Has anyone else seen this/know what causes it? Thanks.

Comment: Turn of GPU acceleration, see: [Update to Chrome 36, black screen, no address bar, can't uninstall](http://superuser.com/a/784943/23133). Did it help any?

Comment: It may have. I rebooted just a little bit ago, so I'll have to wait and see if it comes back. If you re-post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.